# How to create a custom content box next to the address input bar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I just saw that Firefox provides an great addon-builder SDK, but I can't find the information I need to start developing on the following simple addon:

Right under the internet address bar I would like to insert a content area that includes a website (that dynamically loads content).

Which API do I have to use to realize that content window?

Comment: right under the internet address bar? is that 'over' your html?

Answer (score 0):

There is no module for this, you'd have to look at the guts for the Widget module, fork it, and perhaps just change the default position to be in the nav-bar.  Note in Fx25 or 26 the default position for the widget module will be in the nav bar, but the module is deprecated and something easier should be coming which is widget like.